# Conversion of String into Map in Java With Some Special Characters

Tags: java, gson

I am trying to convert a String into Java Map but getting the following exception

**com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException**

This is the string that I am trying to Map.

```
String myString = "{name=Nikhil Gupta,age=23,location=234Niwas@res=34}"
Map innerMap = new Gson().fromJson(myString,Map.class);
```

I understood the main problem here that because of these special characters I am getting this error.
If I remove those spaces and special characters then it will work fine.

Is there any way to do this without removing those spaces and special characters?

The approach used so far.

Wrapped those strings with special characters inside a single quote.

```
String myString = "{name='Nikhil Gupta',age='23',location='234Niwas@res=34'}"
```

But this is something that I don't want to use in a production environment as it will not work with nested structures.

Is there some genuine way to approach this in java?

Comment: "*But this is something that I don't want to use in a production environment as it will not work with nested structures*" can you clarify that (since this is actually correct way to solve your problem - making JSON valid instead of figuring out how to handle invalid one)?

Comment: Why would you not want to use real *valid* JSON in a production environment? You should strive for using standards, so that statement makes little sense. Using valid JSON syntax *is* the "genuine way".

Answer (score 3):

> I understood the main problem here that because of these special characters I am getting this error.

No, it's not because of "special characters" (whatever that means exactly).

```
{name=Nikhil Gupta,age=23,location=234Niwas@res=34}
```

The string you're trying to parse is simply not in JSON format, but in some other format that superficially resembles JSON. Your fixes by enclosing values in single quotes still don't make it JSON.

If it were valid JSON, it would look like this:

```
{"name":"Nikhil Gupta","age":23,"location":"234Niwas@res=34"}
```

Notable differences with your original:

- Keys must be enclosed in double quotes
- String values must be enclosed in double quotes (numeric values do not)
- Key and value must be separated by a colon `:` instead of an equals sign `=`

Ways to solve this:

- Use actual JSON format; see [json.org](https://www.json.org/) for the specification
- If you can't make it real JSON and you must absolutely use the format you are using, then you need to write your own parser for this custom non-JSON format

Answer (score 0):

Convert Map to String

```
 public String triggerStringMapToString(Map<String, String> map)
                    {
                        String str = "";
                        if (map.isEmpty()) return str;
                        
                        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
                            System.out.println(key);
                            str = str.isEmpty() ?
                                 key+"~"+map.get(key):
                                    str+"&"+key+"~"+map.get(key);
                        }
                        return str;
                    }
```

Convert String To MAP

```
public Map<String, String> triggerStrToTriggerStringMap(String triggerStr)
                {
                    
                    return Stream.of(triggerStr.split("&"))
                            .map(str -> str.split("~"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(trigger -> trigger[0], trigger -> trigger[1]));
                }
```